# python - how to decrease elements of an array value

Tags: python, counter

i've created program that looks like this:
[demo](https://ideone.com/h8xdtn)

It works perfectly like i wanted, however how do i reverse this effect? i want to decrese the value to zero (with step value "1") after reaching 1280?

The code is here:

```
matrix=[]
for i in range(0,6):
    matrix.append(0)

matrix[5]=0x0A
i = 1

print matrix
while True:
    matrix[0]=i&0xFF
    i += 1
    if (i > 255):
        matrix[0] = 255
        matrix[1] = i&0xFF
    if (i > 512):
        matrix[1] = 255
        matrix[2] = i&0xFF
    if (i > 768):
        matrix[2] = 255
        matrix[3] = i&0xFF
    if(i > 1024):
        matrix[3] = 255
        matrix[4] = i&0xFF
    print matrix
```

I cannot change the value of "i" to -1 because it's in while loop (i need it that way). So what might be solution in here?

Comment: Why do you think you can not change i to -1?

Comment: because of the while loop - if i change i to "-1" its going to decrese "i" value by 1 and goes back to the beggining - where it increase the i value. 


For example: if I change the value of i to "-1" i will get 1279 - then the third if is going to increase the value back to 1280

Comment: here is the effect if i change i to "-1"  [link](https://imgur.com/a/5jTAg79)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

You should create another variable with which you can change the state of x.

```
matrix=[]
for i in range(0,6):
    matrix.append(0)  

x = 1
counting = 1

print matrix
while True:
    if (x >= 1023):
        counting = -1
    matrix[0]=x&0xFF
    x += counting

    if (x >= 256):
        matrix[0] = 255
        matrix[1] = x&0xFF
    if (x >= 512):
        matrix[1] = 255
        matrix[2] = x&0xFF
    if (x >= 768):
        matrix[2] = 255
        matrix[3] = x&0xFF
    if (x == -1):
        counting = 1
    print matrix
```